# In Seven Card Stud, the dealer missed dealing the last cards and shuffles the deck

Tags: rules, home-game, dealing, dealer, seven-card-stud

After the 6th card is dealt (6 player, 3 have folded) the dealer mix in the dead cards and shuffles the deck (the dealer forgot that we had 1 more card coming).
What should happen now?

Answer (score 3):

There is only really one thing that can happen. Reshuffle, burn and give everyone their 7th card.

The only other option, and this is only because it's a home game, would be to have the players who have folded tell the dealer discreetly their cards, remove them to the muck and then just shuffle whats left. Assuming they can all remember their cards. At least you won't be re-dealing other players cards. This is kinda silly in my opinion but as a home game you could do this.

Comment: You could also tell the players that that's what you intend to do, and if any player objects, allow him to drop out, refunding his contributions to the pot. I would be more inclined to do this if there was significant sixth-street betting, which is often predicated on single out-of-play cards. If it's discovered before betting, then I'd just announce what's going to happen and let them bet knowing that some out-of-play cards might return.

Answer (score 0):

If any cards in the deck have touched any cards in the muck, the hand is void. No reshuffling, no attempt at reconstruction, everyone gets back the chips they had at the start of the hand, the button doesn't move, and you start the hand over like it never happened.

Comment: No casino floorman would ever do this. 6th street is *way* too far into the game to consider a misdeal. The hand must play out, as best the dealer and floor can manage.

Comment: A void hand is very different to a misdeal. A misdeal only applies to the initial deal, but a hand  can be declared void at any time before the pot has been passed out, and it must be declared void if it is discovered that the deck is fouled, or if any irregularity occurs that cannot be reconstructed. For example, a face-up card is dealt that is identical to another card already face up, or a card that should be dealt, to a player or the board, touches the muck before it has been dealt.

Comment: A card being exposed that should have been dealt face down is easy to reconstruct; the card goes back in the deck and it's reshuffled and redealt (or maybe it's replaced by the burn card, depending on the game being dealt). A card in the muck that shouldn't be in the muck is impossible to reconstruct, because you can't retrieve the card and reshuffle it into the deck. If the hand can't continue with *all* the correct cards in play, it's a void hand. No ifs, ands, or buts. No exceptions, ever.

Comment: Yes, a foul deck would be an exception, voiding the hand. But I still think most floormen would let this one play... Yes, there are cards in the deck that shouldn't be, but all the players have that information and there's nothing unfair about continuing.

Comment: A floorman who did let it play is just  being lazy, and deliberately breaking the rules. Anyone who lost money could demand to be reimbursed by the casino, and rightly so, because the hand wasn't completed correctly, and yes, there's a lot unfair about that. There's no way it should ever continue.

Comment: One example that has happened at my casino: Final table of a Texas Hold'em tournament. Heads up on the turn, there's an all in and a call. The guy who is all in is drawing dead. He's going to be out no matter what card comes on the river. The dealer burns, and accidentally drops the next card in the muck before it is exposed. It doesn't matter what the card is; the hand can't be completed with the correct cards in play, so it's a void hand, and he gets a lifeline thanks to a slip of the dealer's hand. It's not really fair in that exact situation, but that's the rule.

Comment: Yeah, that's clearly a case for rule 1: do what's right for the game, even if it's not by the rules. A floorman should not be afraid to make a decision contrary to the rules if it's clearly the right thing to do. The OP's case, frankly, I could argue either way.